# NSMutableAttribute в NSString

Tags: objective-c

Нужно изменить цвет текста в тулбаре у `NSToolbarItem`.
Делаю вот так:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.label];
NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, title.length);
[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:titleRange];
[self setLabel:title];
```

Цвет меняется. Однако в этой строке `[self setLabel:title]` пишет варинг. Есть какие-то не кривые способы перенести `NSMutableAttributeString` в `NSString`?

[image: Warning]

Comment: а можно ворнинг почитать?

Comment: добавил в описание

Answer (score 2):

судя по коду, вы присваиваете объекту UILabel - NSMutableAttributedString. Так делать не стоит, это не правильно, т.к. объекты разных типов. Используйте - setAttributedText к вашему объекту типа UILabel.

Пример:
[yourLabel setAttributedText:title]

Comment: насколько я помню так я сразу делал, но в тогда цвет у строки становится по дефолту черным

Comment: а это потому, что вы при инициализации передали экземпляр UILabel, а не его свойство .text . Проверьте свой код.
 NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.label];
NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, title.length);